# Use only one formula in Excel to count results of multiple COUNTIF

Tags: arrays, excel, count, formula, offset

Hello you all Excel gurus,

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains an undefined number of lines (from 1 to x - x being generally less than 200). Each line has a few initial columns with some data (item number, dates, ...) and, starting at column I, an undefined number of columns (from 1 to x - x being generally less than 50) than can be either empty or contain an "x".

In each line I would like to count the number of "x" (this I know how to do with the COUNTIF function). In a different sheet, I would like to count the number of times the count is 1, the number of times the count is 2, and so on until 6.

Problem for me is that the number of lines and columns being changing, I wanted to put all this in a single formula, using arrays but all my tries failed.

My current formula to get the number of lines totaling 1 is:

`{=SUM(IF(SUM(IF(OFFSET(OFFSET($H$2;1;0;TotalLines;1);0;1;1;TotalColumns)="x";1;0))=1;1;0))}`

With `TotalLines` and `TotalColumns` being named ranges containing the result of lines count and column count respectively, so that I have the exact number of lines and columns currently displayed.

Obviously the formula does not work...

Could you please advise on how to proceed,

Thank you in advance for your support

Comment: If you're always counting numbers in the same row-- row 1 for example-- you can just set your `countif()` range to be `1:1`.  I.e., `=COUNTIF(1:1,6)` to count all the sixes in row 1.  Then you don't need to adjust total columns.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. Actually I would like to replace the 1:1 by an array of results like {1;2;1;1;3;2;....}, each result being a result of a countif(<row>:<row>;"x") for each row of the sheet.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an interim column?

Comment: Only visual... If I add a column far on the right side, the sheet will have an horizontal scroll bar that will scroll to nothing. I feel this is not very clean... but this is me !

Comment: @Yannick I recommend that you have a column not on the far right side, but immediately to the left of your 'data' columns. This means you wont need to keep "inserting columns" when you add more data columns.

Comment: Or consider putting the interim results on a hidden sheet.  Or use a VBA function.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the easiest approach here is to just add in a helper column on the first sheet, where each row has its own COUNTIF function checking the number of "x"s. For clarity to others who may read this (as you are familiar with COUNTIF), I would suggest the following [Put in, say, column D, or whichever column comes immediately after your otherwise-final "data" column", starting in row 2 and dragged down]:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET($D$1,ROW(),1,1,TOTALCOLUMNS),"x")
```

Then in your other tab simply perform a COUNTIF over your individual checks in column D, like so [starting on row 2, assuming that your main data is in Sheet1, and that on Sheet2 column A, you have the number of "x"s you're checking for {1, 2, etc.}]:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!D:D,A2)
```

Comment: Yes this was my first solution. My second was also some udf in `vba`. But using arrays, if possible, would be soooo nice !

Comment: @Yannick I agree with you in principle, however in this case, as you already need to have a raw data tab seperate from your main review tab, I think the simplicity of a helper column outweighs its more unwieldy presentation [as you wont be looking at that tab anyway]. Would it be possible to have, instead of "x", the number 1? Because then you could do a fairly simple Array formula to count the sum of each row, instead of a countif of each row.

Comment: Final thought - while you might see Array Formulas as visually appealing, remember that they are generally harder to review, if you ever hand the workbook over to someone else. Helper columns have the natural advantage of allowing you to explain a calculation at each individual step, instead of needing to do so all at once.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can pivot the first column on countif of yours. Just pick this column and insert a pivot table. Take the same variable to rows and to values as count. If your base table is changed, just refresh it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No sure I can picture what you propose. The thing is that I dont have a column with the `COUNTIF`(because this column would move according to the total  number of columns). Not sure I eplain correctly though...

Comment: You can put your countif column after the max number of columns you suggested. This way it won’t disturb you. Check if the column has a header and then count the X or the nulls

Comment: Actually, if I do this the `pivot` is no longer required. Simple `countif` with `offset` on this column will do the trick. I really was trying to have a single array-type formula. If this is not possible then bad luck but knowing a little about Excel, I doubt this is impossible... :)